# MOSFET stocking question ("jelly bean")

Tags: discussion

This question [Which are the more modern "Jelly bean" MOSFETs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586225/which-are-the-more-modern-jelly-bean-mosfets) is quickly attracting downvotes, and I think some meta discussion is in order...

This looks like a 'canonical question' about selecting mosfets, with the idea of which are good products to select for stocking a lab.

There is good information here, and I'd like to salvage it if possible, but I do see some issues.

- product selection vs shopping questions
- lists of things tend to get out of date
- misuse of tags ('jelly' and 'bean' don't work as standalone tags)

Meta is the right place to discuss the best way to approach this type of content.

Comment: **SITE RULE** - *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: Except for specific model numbers, which are as specific as 2N3904 (any manufacturer could make them), my post was not about any specific manufacturer, and definitely not about "places of purchase" as I have not even mentioned A SINGLE ONE, and have looked over multiple sources for the price (which I have given as a RANGE and not so specifically), so my list was as generic as it could be, definitely not serving as an advertisement or promotion for any manufacturer or distributor. My situation and problem faced by MULTITUDES of electronics enthusiasts were described and solutions suggested.

Comment: Your list was "generic" to you @EdinFifić and, it will become out of date (even to you). Updating your answer regularly (in order to try and keep the info current) positions your question at the top of the list of active questions and pushes more recent and likely much more relevant questions down the pile into a more obscure position hence, your Q and A should be stopped immediately.

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems like a poster child for why we *don't* want list questions. I really see no reason at all to keep this.

You mention *"There is good information here"* but only list the negative parts, so I'm not even sure what they are. Even a link to a pre-sorted list of MOSFETs from a component distributor would be a better answer, at least it would be up to date.

As the (so far only) answer shows, it's also very opinion-based. I would likely not keep *any* of the MOSFETs listed. A V<sub>GS</sub> over 5 volts is useless to me, and in my opinion useless to anyone who deals with breadboards and through-hole components. Should I answer with my own list? How many lists should we have?

No, it's just a bad question, it goes against a number of policies that have been collected from many years of experience.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that there are information obsolescence concerns brought up by @pipe, my concern is that  "Jelly beans" are ambiguous,  highly context specific,  and regional in practice. The first answer demonstrates this, focusing on through hole part numbers with modest parameters suitable for small protoboard projects. (Which, was also a concern expressed by @pipe)

Also, worth it to mention: jelly bean is highly regional jargon!

Perhaps a way to salvage the question and provide some value to the community  is to narrow the scope, for example to focus on through hole MOSFETs for small signal applications ( under 50V, low vgs) which have been in production for more than ten years. Just an example.

This might not address the relevance concerns expressed by some, but it would at least make the information with more added value than a scrape of a vendor parts list sorted by price.

P.s. it appears to me that the person asking and answering is earnest, excited, and attempting to expand their learnings with additional practical knowledge of electronics . Often the practical and logistical side of the industry feels like dark arts more than operational science.  I feel that we should encourage that knowledge seeking . Of course, while trying to avoid the very valid issues that many have brought up. I really hope there is a way to salvage the intent behind this question  into something that is useful for the community and where the OP also feels validated in their question

Comment: Thank you for your objective observation. I do have many years of experience and study in electronics, professionally and hobby-wise, while only recently using MOSFETs more often, and I have wasted literally hundreds, if not thousands of hours looking for MOSFETs as common and useful as 2N3904 in the BJT world for example, and I see nothing wrong with presenting such equivalents in the MOSFET world. In fact, it is very much needed to help out thousands of people who are as confused as I was for a long time, and I am STILL searching for the best compromise.

Comment: I feel that my post was attacked and voted down without giving it a fair and balanced overview and chance, or considering its value and usefulness. An electronics technician's, engineer's or hobbyist's time should be spent worrying about HOW to connect a component in a circuit, NOT wasted in an extremely long search for suitable parts. We have a limited time in our lives, and we should use it SOLVING problems instead of looking for the answers that a million people have already wasted so much of their time on, but the results were very rarely shared, and thus my question and answer post.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fear that such a thing simply  doesn't exist simply because the market and types of applications for MOSFETs is so much more diverse and the technology far more advanced  than when the 2N3904 was developed.

Comment: Yes, I felt that there was some tension that wasn't strictly needed. Clearly everyone involved was acting in good faith and have demonstrated contributions to the community. However, I agree with some of the comments I would still vote to close as-is.

Comment: Perhaps we can continue in chat? (Moderator?)

Comment: No need for chat, I try to have my questions, answers and discussions down to a necessary minimum, as I have many other problems to solve. There ARE MOSFET equivalents to the BJTs, 2N7000 being such an example, with a voltage range even wider than 2N3904, similar current, just as cheap (one commenter mentioned price as an issue, apparently unaware how cheap the 2N7000 is in some places and quantities). A few people have negatively criticized my post without giving it a chance, and I can see from their comments that they are not looking at the whole picture, maybe not even caring about it.

Comment: I agree there are equivalents (specs) and there are drop in replacements, both of which would more likely be acceptable questions, but the idea of "generic" is,  in my view, an opinion. (Generic for who?)

Comment: Generic for the vast majority of projects and uses, and for the vast majority of those who want to build something but need cheap parts that will cover most of their needs.

Comment: @EdinFifić no, those parts are not generic to *"the vast majority of projects and uses"* and each time you update your answer (to try and keep it up-to-date) you push valid questions down the list of current questions. It's a selfish Q and A and, it's against site rules for very good reasons.

Comment: @EdinFifić You have wasted thousands of hours searching for a mosfet? Good lord.

Comment: @BlairFonville Maybe not thousands, and had I searched just for a specific purpose I would have spent less time. The time I include in this search is also the time spent going over various schematics, blogs, posts and recommendations, coupled with my many searches through various outlets, distributors and vendors at different times with different aspects, perspectives, parameters. Many of them were "by the way" searches at the "spur of the moment", giving me new and better insights over time, so yeah, quite possibly reached over a 1000 hours, and not just for "a MOSFET", but multiple MOSFETs.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds familiar and quite normal for someone designing what sounds like dozens of circuits per month. Which is a prodigious amount. In my view , the careful and methodical selection of parts, comes with the territory of being an Electrical **Engineer**  . Everyone goes through it, so it feels easier every time,  but the process of careful selection of components is just part of the gig.

Answer (score -3):

I have tried to sum up 2 years of my research and headaches about this subject, and spent a few hours writing the post in question, because I have seen this question many times on many sites/forums, and wanted to spare many others from the same headaches and time-wasting I have experienced.

However, this was interpreted by some as self-centered and "selfish" on my part, so I see no need to waste any more of my time and energy trying to convince such people otherwise.

I apologize for my "selfishness" here.

Comment: So post your answer on those _forums_ where people asked. Stack Exchange is not designed for list questions and "what's the best ---?" questions.

Comment: For a forum that supports discussion I suggest that you look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements and problems as possible. 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively), and are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.

Comment: Thank you very much, Russell. I will check it out.